# Saving player data in SQL

Tags: java, sql, json

Okay so this is the code which saves my player data to SQL and loads it and it's the new way which I'm trying to use and it works fine for everything else except for loading the inventory.

```
public static int loadPlayer(Player player) throws Exception {
    int returnCode = 1;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais;
    ObjectInputStream ins;

    PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerName = ? LIMIT 1");
    ps.setString(1, player.getUsername());
    ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();

    if (results.next()) {
        if (!results.getString("password").equalsIgnoreCase(/*Misc.stringToMD5(*/player.getPassword()/*)*/)) {
            returnCode = 2;
        } else {
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(results.getBytes("playerData"));
            ins = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

            PlayerData data = (PlayerData) ins.readObject();
            data.convertPlayerData(player);

            ins.close();
            bais.close();
            returnCode = 0;
        }
    }
    ps.close();
    return returnCode;
}

public static void savePlayer(Player player) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

    oos.writeObject(new PlayerData(player).getObject());
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    bos.close();
    if (!userExists(player)) {
        ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO players (playerName, password, playerData) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, player.getUsername());
        ps.setString(2, /*Misc.stringToMD5(*/player.getPassword()/*)*/);
        ps.setBytes(3, bos.toByteArray());
    } else {
        ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE players SET playerData = ? WHERE playerName = ?");
        ps.setObject(1, bos.toByteArray());
        ps.setString(2, player.getUsername());
    }
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
}

public static class PlayerData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7156373174557675162L;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;
    private byte rights;

    private Item[] inventory;

    /**
     * Feels the local data with the players details
     * 
     * @param player
     *            the player
     */
    public PlayerData(Player player) {
        x = player.getLocation().getX();
        y = player.getLocation().getY();
        z = player.getLocation().getZ();
        rights = ((byte) player.getRights());

        inventory = player.getInventory().getItems();
    }

    /**
     * Convert the data to our player
     * 
     * @param player
     *            convert out local data to the player
     */
    public void convertPlayerData(Player player) {
        player.getLocation().setAs(new Location(x, y, z));
        player.setRights(rights);

        if (inventory != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
                player.getInventory().getItems()[i] = ItemCheck.check(player, inventory[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Return the player details as object
     * 
     * @return the object
     */
    public Object getObject() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

And this is the old system with json which works fine and loads inventory.

```
public static final class PlayerContainer {
    private final Item[] inventory;

    public PlayerContainer(Player player) {
        inventory = player.getInventory().getItems();
    }

    public void parseDetails(Player player) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./data/characters/containers/" + player.getUsername() + ".json", false));
        try {
            writer.write(PlayerSave2.GSON.toJson(this));
            writer.flush();
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }

    public static boolean loadDetails(Player player) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("./data/characters/containers/" + player.getUsername() + ".json");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            return false;
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            PlayerContainer details = PlayerSave2.GSON.fromJson(reader, PlayerContainer.class);

            if (details.inventory != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < details.inventory.length; i++) {
                    player.getInventory().getItems()[i] = ItemCheck.check(player, details.inventory[i]);
                    System.out.println("Inv: "+details.inventory[i]);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the BLOB output I'm getting in SQL:

```
'[Lorg.saranthium.game.entity.item.Item;´×o<s°9x
```

JSON output

```
inventory":[{"id":4151,"amount":1},null,null ...
```

So why doesn't this work properly on SQL?

Comment: So, where is the code loading the inventory from the database. Which code gives you that output? But more importantly, why do you store a binary snapshot of your data that will be impossible to read back as soon as you slightly change the class in a relational database?

Comment: I'm still not seeing Player.getInventory, which seems like it could be the thing failing. I also don't understand what you're doing in convertPlayerData/loadDetails where you're copying, with some filtering by ItemCheck.check, the inventory from the inventory you got when the class was instantiated to inventory you're getting every time through the loop. On storing a serialized version of the object, being it has a serialVersionUID I think it will work, but just because it will work doesn't make it a good idea. Storing serialized data is almost never a good idea, and definitely not here.

Comment: It's just a getter for the the Inventory class. And it's definately not the cause of the problem, because it's loading correctly with JSON with same code. Convertplayerdata is what makes it load for the live player.